# MBeans are not being shown in jvisualVM

Tags: java, spring-integration, mbeans, spring-jmx

[Gary Russels's Monitoring Spring Integration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fkZcF47NRu0) application is great.

I would like to add simple MBean to monitor the application.
Here is my code:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ManagedResource(objectName="myapp:application=hello")

public class HelloBean {

    @ManagedOperation
    public String sayHello(String name) {
       return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

I also added the following in spring-context xml file:

```
<context:mbean-server />
<int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="spring.application" />

<bean id="helloBean" class="com.example.HelloBean" />
```

when I look in jVisualVM, I do not see the bean. I can see MessageChannel in spring.application domain but not my MBean.
[image: image of MBeans in spring.integration]

is there any thing else to be done to get annotated MBeans to show in visualVM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<context:mbean-export/>` is for you.

The `<int-jmx:mbean-export>` is a custom `MBeanExporter` for Spring Integration components. Everything else should be managed by the standard Spring `<context:mbean-export/>`.

Comment: Thats perfect. I added <context:mbean-export/> and I can see my bean.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to implement the same with Java DSL only in SI 4.x?

Comment: I guess you what to see this: `EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-mbean-exporter